# GET Error Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hi Everyone i am trying to create api using raw sql query, but when i hit url getting Object of type byte is not json serualizable,
please help me out how to solve this Error

**views.py**  # this is views file where i have executing my query. input pararmeter is start_date,end_date, team_id, dates, in error u can see the url path also.

```
def car_report(request):
    start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
    print(start_date,'start_date')
    end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')
    print(end_date,'end_date')
    dates = request.GET.getlist('dates[]')
    print(dates,'dates')
    team_id = int(request.GET.get('team_id'))
    print(team_id,'team_id')
    car_report= connection.cursor()
    car_report.execute(''' SELECT
                                temp2.car_number,sum(temp2.trips)as total_trips, temp2.status,
                                case 
                                when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                else sum(temp2.day1_trips) end AS day1_trips,
                                case 
                                when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                else sum(temp2.day2_trips) end AS day2_trips,
                                case 
                                when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                else sum(temp2.day3_trips) end AS day3_trips,
                                case 
                                when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                else sum(temp2.day4_trips) end AS day4_trips,
                                case 
                                when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                else sum(temp2.day5_trips) end AS day5_trips,
                                case 
                                when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                else sum(temp2.day6_trips) end AS day6_trips,
                                case 
                                when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                else sum(temp2.day7_trips) end AS day7_trips
                                FROM
                                (
                                SELECT temp1.car_number,temp1.trips,temp1.status,
                                case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day1_trips,
                                case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day2_trips,
                                case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day3_trips,
                                case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day4_trips,
                                case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0  end as day5_trips,
                                case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day6_trips,
                                case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day7_trips
                                from
                                (SELECT date, car_number,driver_id,trips,car_status,status,
                                case when trips=0
                                THEN
                                CASE WHEN
                                car_status = 'BREAKDOWN'
                                THEN -10
                                when car_status='ND'
                                then -20
                                when car_status='REPAIR'
                                then -30
                                when car_status='INSURANCE'
                                then -40
                                when car_status='PARKING'
                                then -50
                                ELSE 0
                                END
                                else trips end as trip
                                FROM fleet_car_dash_daily WHERE team_id= %s 
                                and (date BETWEEN %s and %s))as temp1) temp2 GROUP by temp2.car_number''',
                                [dates[0],dates[1],dates[2],dates[3],dates[4],dates[5],dates[6],team_id,start_date,end_date])
    car_report_data = car_report.fetchall()
    print(car_report_data,'car_report_data')
    json_res=[]
    for row in car_report_data:
        json_obj=dict(car_number=row[0],total_trips=row[1],status=row[2],day1_trips=row[3],day2_trips=row[4],day3_trips=row[5],day4_trips=row[6],day5_trips=row[7],day6_trips=row[8],day7_trips=row[9])
        print(json_obj,'json_obj')
        json_res.append(json_obj)
    return JsonResponse(json_res,safe=False)
```

**Error-** after execution getting this error

```
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
ERROR "GET /fleet/car_report?start_date=2022-04-04+&end_date=2022-04-10+&team_id=1&dates%5B%5D=2022-04-04+&dates%5B%5D=2022-04-05+&dates%5B%5D=2022-04-06+&dates%5B%5D=2022-04-07+&dates%5B%5D=2022-04-08+&dates%5B%5D=2022-04-09+&dates%5B%5D=2022-04-10+ HTTP/1.1" 500 126431
```

Comment: You have a typo.  Change ```... temp2 GROUP by temp2.car_number''',``` to ```... temp2 GROUP by temp2.car_number''' % ```

Comment: but i don't issue with sql query but when  use this sql query to create api then i am getting error.

Comment: 1)  change ``` ... temp2 GROUP by temp2.car_number''',``` to ```... temp2 GROUP by temp2.car_number''' % ```.  2) Add a opening parenthesis.  i.e ```( dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,team_id,start_date,end_date)```

Comment: while change this not getting error but receive empty output

Comment: i have print paramter now getting this -2022-04-04 date
2022-04-05 team_id
2022-04-06 start_date
2022-04-07 end_date

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.

Firstly, the part of the code:

```
 car_report.execute(''' SELECT
                                    temp2.car_number,sum(temp2.trips)as total_trips, temp2.status,
                                    case 
                                    when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                    when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                    when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                    when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                    when sum(temp2.day1_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                    else sum(temp2.day1_trips) end AS day1_trips,
                                    case 
                                    when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                    when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                    when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                    when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                    when sum(temp2.day2_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                    else sum(temp2.day2_trips) end AS day2_trips,
                                    case 
                                    when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                    when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                    when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                    when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                    when sum(temp2.day3_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                    else sum(temp2.day3_trips) end AS day3_trips,
                                    case 
                                    when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                    when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                    when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                    when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                    when sum(temp2.day4_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                    else sum(temp2.day4_trips) end AS day4_trips,
                                    case 
                                    when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                    when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                    when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                    when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                    when sum(temp2.day5_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                    else sum(temp2.day5_trips) end AS day5_trips,
                                    case 
                                    when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                    when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                    when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                    when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                    when sum(temp2.day6_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                    else sum(temp2.day6_trips) end AS day6_trips,
                                    case 
                                    when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-10 then 'BD' 
                                    when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-20 then 'ND'
                                    when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-30 then 'R'
                                    when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-40 then 'I'
                                    when sum(temp2.day7_trips)=-50 then 'P'
                                    else sum(temp2.day7_trips) end AS day7_trips
                                    FROM
                                    (
                                    SELECT temp1.car_number,temp1.trips,temp1.status,
                                    case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day1_trips,
                                    case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day2_trips,
                                    case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day3_trips,
                                    case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day4_trips,
                                    case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0  end as day5_trips,
                                    case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day6_trips,
                                    case when temp1.date= %s then temp1.trip else 0 end as day7_trips
                                    from
                                    (SELECT date, car_number,driver_id,trips,car_status,status,
                                    case when trips=0
                                    THEN
                                    CASE WHEN
                                    car_status = 'BREAKDOWN'
                                    THEN -10
                                    when car_status='ND'
                                    then -20
                                    when car_status='REPAIR'
                                    then -30
                                    when car_status='INSURANCE'
                                    then -40
                                    when car_status='PARKING'
                                    then -50
                                    ELSE 0
                                    END
                                    else trips end as trip
                                    FROM fleet_car_dash_daily WHERE team_id= %s 
                                    and (date BETWEEN %s and %s))as temp1) temp2 GROUP by temp2.car_number''',
                                    dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,team_id,start_date,end_date)
```

Firstly,  you need to change  `temp2.car_number''',` to  `temp2.car_number''' %`

Secondly, you need to add a `(` before the list of fields..

i.e.

```
                                    (dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,team_id,start_date,end_date)
```

So in conclusion:

```
  ...
  FROM fleet_car_dash_daily WHERE team_id= %s 
  and (date BETWEEN %s and %s)) as temp1) temp2 GROUP by temp2.car_number''' %
  (dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,dates,team_id,start_date,end_date)
```

Comment: update my code but still getting empty output

Comment: My answer only solves your syntax errors.  I don't know what information you're supposed to get from that long sql command.